# How to include JavaScript files properly in (ASP.NET) project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, include

I have ASP.NET (4.0) web site which in turn has some JavaScript on it. As time goes I include more and more JS files into my aspx and ascx files. Usually I just add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script1.js"></script>
```

That works fine for small add-ons, but in some cases script1 references to script2 and I need to add one more reference IN EACH PLACE where script1 is used.

Is that the proper way to include JS files? Or I would better load script2.js from script1.js ([How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)) that will guarantee it will be always included?

Could you please recommend references on the "best practice" with regards to this topic. I've googled for some, but found way too many links and really sank...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this WebForms or MVC? Check out "bundling and minification" which were first introduced with MVC but are now available in WebForms, depending upon which version of VS you are using (2013).

Comment: Classis ASP.NET (Web Forms)

Comment: Master pages are probably what you want. What I do is have a utility function that inserts `<script>` objects into the page during `Page_Load()`, but I'm working under DotNetNuke where I can't use master pages.

Comment: Bundling all your third-party scripts into one would also work and help with performance a bit. (That said, I think it's usually just as good or maybe better to use a parallel script loader like yepnope.js.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to base your forms on a MasterPage and then reference all of your js file in the head section of your MasterPage.